Mikraot Gedolot Recommendation
I currently use Mossad HaRav Kook's Torat Chaim mikraot gedolot. The content is excellent, but the print quality and size, as well as the format, are a bit rough on the eyes. I am looking for a recommendation for a new mikraot gedolot with the following features.

Clear, easy to read font and format

All Hebrew

Accurate

No censorship (e.g. excluding Rashbam's comment in Bereshit about the day beginning in the morning rather than the evening)

Not too bulky to carry (comparable to Torat Chaim)


Can anyone recommend an edition that fulfills those criteria?
Thank you.

There's the Bar Ilan Mikraot Gedolot haKeter. I really want to get my hands on it

@NoachMiFrankfurt IIRC, it had an astronomical price...

@Kazibácsi, hence it being on my wishlist, rather than in my personal otzar sefarim

I can personally recommend Bar Ilan's Mikraot Gedolot. It has everything you can ask for, and unlike Artscroll, does not have a history of censorship. Here's a description of their work:

The Mikraot Gedolot HaKeter is a project of Bar-Ilan University, based
on the most accurate Bible manuscript, the Aleppo codex.
Thousands of flaws of previous editions have been corrected. It
includes an apparatus called "Ein Ha-Masorah"' which makes the
terminology of the Masorah readil comprehensible.
The Aramaic targumim and commentaries are based on meticulous
comparison of the best extant manuscripts. It includes the most
comprehensive selection of medieval commentaries, which have been
printed in an easily readable Hebrew font and are clearly punctuated,
securing its establishment as an indispensable study and research
tool.

They recently finished the complete Tanakh, and sell a more affordable small edition of it here.
I'm attaching a couple of pictures from their edition of Yechezkel, including extra material at the back of the book.




It says hardcover not available for purchase on the website. This edition looks amazing. Any idea where else to purchase it?

@Bs234570 You can find it in Sefarim online stores, like this one: https://www.aron-hasfarim.co.il/product.asp?productid=2728. Also, Bar Ilan puts out their commentaries for free online here: https://www.mgketer.org/
